# What is a single word for a person who is underestimated?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What is a single word for **a person** who is underestimated in this situation:

> a group of people underestimates/humiliates one of its members by treating her/him so bad, i.e. verbal abuse, harassment, rudeness and such.

Comment: **Underestimate** means to **misjudge** it is different than **humiliate**. Does your victim seek vengeance (one would expect this if they are underestimated)? Being treated this way, they are being **bullied**

Comment: Because a person is **disrespected** it does not mean they are **underestimated**. Are you actually thinking of a different word?

Comment: By **underestimate** do you mean the person is held in **low esteem** by the people abusing them and people **don't think much of** that person?

Comment: Yes. The person isn't given any chance to speak up as well.

Comment: Wow , this quesion went everywhere but to an answer. It seems" readily underestimated " is about as good as I can manage as well. I was looking for the same , to describe a person who is just that as well. There doesn't seem to be a word that carries the proper connotation and intent.

Answer (score 2):

Such a person is often called a [*pariah*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+pariah).

Originally the word referred to a member of a particular Indian caste.  Nowadays, it is used to refer to anyone who is disrespected, ignored and is denied a chance to put their case.

Comment: I am an Indian and this word is very much from my mother tongue as well! Never thought of this! +1

Answer (score 0):

The word *'[outcast](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outcast)'* may suit for humiliation; on the other hand, *an [underdog](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/underdog)* would mean to *underestimate* someone for their efforts/work.

Answer (score -1):

[Underdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdog) fits what you are looking for:

> An underdog is a person or group in a competition, usually in sports and creative works, who is not favored to win and popularly expected to lose. The party, team, or individual expected to win is called the favorite or top dog. In the case where an underdog wins, the outcome is an upset.